# Java Generic return dynamic type

Tags: java, generics

Imagine a situation where you have this:

```
// Marker
interface Type {}

interface CustomType extends Type {
    int getSomething();
    int getAnotherThing();
}

class CustomTypeImpl implements CustomType {
    public int getSomething() {
        return 1;
    }
    public int getAnotherThing() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

In another class, I want to have a generic method like this :

```
public <T extends CustomType> T getFromInterface(Class<T> clazz)
```

that return an implementation of the class I put in parameter. For example, I want to call this method like below : `SomeInstanceOfClass.getFromInterface(CustomType.class)` and it returns an instance of `CustomTypeImpl`.

**@EDIT** : I forgot to mention that I have access to a method that stores all interfaces that can be used as argument of `getFromInterface(Class<T> clazz)` method.

The signature of this method is : `public Set<? extends Class<? extends Type>> allTypes()`

How can I manage to do this please ?

Comment: What if interface has two implementations? If it never does, then what's the point of an interface anyway?

Comment: Actually, I have a marker interface that permits to have a common type for my objects. The situation is something like : interface Type{//marker} interface CustomType extends Type{//look above} and my implementation. In fact, I have other interfaces that extends Type and then I have an implementation for each interface that extends Type.

Comment: The answer might solve your question, but I think there's probably a much better solution to whatever your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection and create a new instance with the class object. The information about what class implements some interface can be stored in some map.

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> interfaceToImplementationMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>() {{
    put(CustomType.class, CustomTypeImpl.class);
}};

public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    CustomType instance = getFromInterface(CustomType.class);
    System.out.println(instance);
}

public static <T> T getFromInterface(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return clazz.cast(interfaceToImplementationMap.get(clazz).newInstance());
}
```

Comment: There are many web pages explaining why you should never use “double brace initialization.”  Use a single static initialization block instead.  Aside from that, good answer.

Comment: And that is true. I absolutely agree with the above comment. I would like also recommend taking a look on com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap and its static method - builder from the guava library.